# How to build Magento 2 Mega Menu with Custom CSS?

Tags: magento2, navigation

I'm trying to figure out how to create a mega menu with **custom css only / no extensions** ?

I copied over the `Magento/Catalog/Plugin/Block/Topmenu` block to begin. But not sure what to do next or where to find the HTML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IN magento2, menu's html is generate from `Magento\Theme\Block\Html;`e

At this class's

- `_getHtml()`. first level menu items
- `_addSubMenu()` add ***sub menu HTML code for current menu item***.ne

**Basic  this block  class generate Html content for menu**

Add   the ***menu.js*** **`(vendor/magento/module-theme/view/frontend/web/)`**   used at Menu

For ***css use less file** `_navigation.less` at  `**vendor\magento\theme-frontend-blank\web\css\source**`.

Comment: Thanks Amit, when I copy over Magento\Theme\Block\Html\Topmenu and run my page I get this error: [message] => Uncaught TypeError: Argument 2 passed to Magento\Theme\Block\Html\Topmenu::__construct() must be an instance of Magento\Framework\Data\Tree\NodeFactory, array given, called in /var/www/business/app/code/Comapny/Topmenu/Block/Html/Topmenu.php on line 52 and defined in /var/www/business/vendor/magento/module-theme/Block/Html/Topmenu.php:46

Comment: Please share code of `/var/www/business/app/code/Comapny/Topmenu/Block/Html/Topmen‌​u.php`.